# Bypassing size limitation on a subprocess command

Tags: python, size, subprocess, buffer, maxlength

I need your help to solve my problem. I want to launch a powershell command using subprocess. However the command used will be very long, so it will be bigger than the size of the buffer. I have done many tests and right now I'm not able to find a good solution. 
I would like to split my big buffer (it's a base64 content) into small buffers but I don't know how to do using subprocess.

For example, here is my subprocess call:

```
a = "a" * 32716
command = ["powershell.exe", "/c", "$base64='%s'\n" % a, "Write-Host $base64"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

It works if the size of the variable "*a*" is less than 32717, if it's bigger (ex: equals to 32717) I have the following error: **WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect**. If it's a lot bigger, I have this error: **WindowsError: [Error 206] The filename or extension is too long**.

I tried to split the "*command*" variable into small buffers but the content of the buffer is not by cell, it's a concatenation of the entire tab, so it doesn't change the problem.

```
command = ["powershell.exe", "/c", "$base64=" + small_buffer1, "$base64=$base64+" small_buffer2, etc.]
```

Another idea was to use different subprocess calls. The problem is I cannot concatenate a variable because it will not be defined on the same powershell instance. So between subprocess, I will lose the "*base64*" content.

```
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "/c", "$base64='%s'\n" % a], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# $base64 will be empty
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "/c", "Write-Host $base64"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If anyone has an idea, it will be very nice. I think, it would be possible to define one instance of powershell and add buffers into it as an interactive shell.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't know much about powershell, but have you considered dumping your long argument/command into a temporary file, and either piping it into a powershell invocation (you could do it this way with bash), or, from within powershell grabbing the temporary file's contents?

Comment: I will do it if I don't find any solutions. I wanted to do it all in memory. If it's not possible I will write a temporary file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I've found is easy to implement. The goal is to keep the subprocess open and to write the buffer in stdin. 
Here is an example:

```
# keep the pipe open
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)

# initialize the powershell value
p.stdin.write("$data=\"\""+"\n")

# split the buffer to small buffers
size = 25000
tab = [veryLongLine[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(veryLongLine), size)]
for t in tab:
    # concatenate small buffers to obtain the "veryLongLine" value
    p.stdin.write("$data+=\"%s\"\n" % t)

    # flush the buffer every time (the $data value is not flushed)        
    p.stdin.flush()

# write the output
p.stdin.write("Write-Host $data\n")
```

Hope it will help !